# How to play audio without being root (via sudo)?

Tags: audio, sudo

In order to play audio (espeak or aplay for example) I have to be root (via sudo). How can I do those as just a regular user? Is there a group I must be a member of or do I have to change some permissions somewhere? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The user has to be in the audio group:

```
gpasswd -a [user] audio
```

Answer (score 9):

have you tried:

```
adduser <username> audio
```

as suggested [here](http://docs.mopidy.com/en/latest/installation/raspberrypi/), or:

```
usermod -a -G audio <username>
```

as suggested [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=16013).

Comment: It's good to suggest adduser and addgroup rather than more primitive alternatives.