# Command aplay does not work without sudo

Tags: audio, raspbian-stretch, alsa, audio-playback

The command `aplay` only works if preceded by `sudo`. `omxplayer test.wav` will play the audio I recorded with `arecord` just fine. `aplay text.wav` does not, but `sudo aplay test.wav` does. [The suggestions from this previous thread did not solve the issue.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3637/how-to-play-audio-without-being-root-via-sudo) HDMI is definitely the default audio output.

The error I get from `aplay test.wav`:

```
aplay: main:788: audio open error: No such file or directory
```

Similar problems with `speaker-test`. When doing `sudo speaker-test` it works, but on its own I get:

```
Playback open error: -2,No such file or directory
```

`aplay --list-devices` returns:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
 card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
 Subdevices: 7/7
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
 Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
 Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
 Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
 Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
 Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
 Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

And `ls -l /dev/snd` returns

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       60 Jul 19 18:22 by-id
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       80 Jul 19 18:22 by-path
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  0 Jul 19 18:22 controlC0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 32 Jul 19 18:22 controlC1
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 16 Jul 19 18:22 pcmC0D0p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 17 Jul 19 18:22 pcmC0D1p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 56 Jul 19 18:22 pcmC1D0c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 Jul 19 18:22 seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Jul 19 18:22 timer
```

Comment: what does `aplay --list-devices` produce

Comment: And what is the output of `ls -l /dev/snd/`?

Comment: I edited the main question with this info

Answer (score 3):

Check if your user included in the audio group. This might be necessary for `aplay` to run. If not, you can add the user to the group by running:

```
sudo adduser "yourname" audio
```

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted. Adding to the `audio` group then rebooting fixed the problem for me.

Comment: The solution works for me too on - Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-1044-raspi aarch64).
Thankyou so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup audio output device like described in https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/audio-config.md

I had the same issue, after update of rpi there was no sound anymore (HDMI in my case) - so nothing from aplay, chromium, etc running as `pi` user, but it works fine as `root` (or under `sudo`).

User `pi` was initially (and still is) in `audio` group.

This 2 things helped to solve that for me:

```bsh
rm .asoundrc; # no idea why it has also bothered sound output on my side

sudo raspi-config
# select "System Options" -> "Audio" -> and choose the audio output ("HDMI 1" in my case), then "Finish".
```